# check if string contains 6 or more of the same digit

Tags: python, postgresql, validation

I need a python or postgres script that will check if string contains duplicate of 6 or more digits in it. For example `"811811113111711","822222222255555"` should give true, and `"812345678901234"` should give false. String is a number, always of the same `length - 16` and `starts with 8`, that is validated before this.

Currently have this but it's a very basic solution and only work for the characters next to each other and I need all in the number.

```py
a_string = "811111111111111"
matches = ["000000", "111111", "222222", "333333", "444444", "555555", "666666", "777777", "888888", "999999"]

if any([x in a_string for x in matches]):
    print('true')
else:
    print('false')
```

Comment: Did you mean: `any([x in sorted(a_string) for x in matches])`? This will bring together all the repeated digits. Does the leading `8` count towards one of the `8` digits?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely want to use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). This can be thought like a multiset, i.e. a set that can have multiple occurences of a value. It's implemented with a dictionary where the keys are the set items and the values are the number of occurenecs.

For example,

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter("11333111333")
Counter({'3': 6, '1': 5})
```

From there one you can filter the counter to see if you have relevant data:

```
some_counter = Counter(some_string)
duplicate_digits = {k : v for k,v in some_counter.items() if k in "0123456789" and v >= 6}
```

if `duplicate_digits` is not empty, you have counted successfully a digit more than six times.